# How to Encrypt and decrypt a captured images in react native?

Tags: react-native, encryption

I am an beginner in react native. I am able to capture images using react-native-image-picker and I am able to upload captured photo's to aws s3. But, I want to encrypt or hash the captured images in android device and before upload I need to decrypt them. That is taken photo's must be encrypted/hashed inside the mobile, Through my app only I need to decrypt them. How can I implement this.

There are two methods,

In takePic method I want to encrypt it before storing in the device and in upload method, I want to decrypt them before uploading. I googled it. But I did not get any proper documentation on this.

Can you please help to do this?

My code is,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Picker,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
import { RNS3 } from "react-native-aws3";

export default class SecondScreen extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: "",
      saveImages: []
    };
  }

  takePic() {
    const options = {
          quality: 1.0,
          maxWidth: 50,
          maxHeight: 50,
      }
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options,(responce)=>{
      const file = {
        uri: responce.uri,
        name: responce.fileName,
        method: "POST",
        path: responce.path,
        type: responce.type,
        notification: {
          enabled: true
        }
      };
      this.state.saveImages.push(file);
    });
  }
  _upload = saveImages => {
    const config = {
      keyPrefix: "uploads/",
      bucket: "myBukectName",
      region: "us-east-2",
      accessKey: "***",
      secretKey: "***",
      successActionStatus: 201
    };

    this.state.saveImages.map(image => {
      RNS3.put(image, config).then(responce => {
        console.log(saveImages);
      });
    });

    //once after upload is done delete from the gallary
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.Camera}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePic.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Take Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.Send}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._upload()}>
            <Text>Send</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using react-native-base64 and I am doing decryption in server side using python. (Getting base64 data from the file and decoding it.)

takePic(){

```
//set of other codes
   const base64 = RNFS.writeFile(responce.uri, responce.data);
   return base64;
   //this will create the base64 image file
```

}

Comment: Base64 is not encryption